# Long lines in LaTeX

Tags: latex, long-lines

I have some code I write inside the verbatim environment. Sometimes, the lines are too long and the generated pdf looks ugly - the text row passes over the right margin. What can I do to automatically break these long lines? Is there anything better than the verbatim env?

Thanks,
Lucian

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you just use a fixed-width font, e.g. `\texttt{}`? If you require something more sophisticated, try the [moreverb](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moreverb/), [listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/), or [algorithmicx](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/) packages.

Answer (score 11):

Of course, you have the wonderful "listings" package for that. It supports (if you want) even pretty printing of a lot of source code languages, as well as a "smart breaking" of long lines depending on the language being displayed.

Answer (score 3):

I'd strongly advise making use of the listings package for that. It will format code nicely, and supports a large number of languages (See [Pg12](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)), and is effectively used in three ways:

1. Inline snippets are included using the `\lstinline!int x = 0;!` command
2. Typed code blocks, within the `lstlisting` environment, such as the following

   ```
   \begin{lstlisting}
   for i:=maxint to 0 do
   begin
   { do nothing }
   end;
   \end{lstlisting}
   ```
3. Imported code blocks where code is embedded in a document directly from a source-code file, using, for example, `\lstinputlisting{source.py}`

There are many, many options that can be configured with this package to, for example, wrap lines and include line numbers, and full details can be found in the [package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), but a good basic setup is provided in the [wikibook entry](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings):

```
\lstset{ %
language=C,                     % choose the language of the code
basicstyle=\footnotesize,       % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
numberstyle=\footnotesize,      % the size of the fonts that are used for the line-numbers
stepnumber=2,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1 each line will be numbered
numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
frame=single,                  % adds a frame around the code
tabsize=2,                    % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
escapeinside={\%*}{*)}          % if you want to add a comment within your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try a pretty-printing package like LGrind.  Otherwise you will have to manually
break the lines.

Answer (score 1):

You might also be interested in the [fancyvrb package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/).